# Erro no CSS - Django FormField

Tags: css3, django, python-3.x, bootstrap-3

Esta dando o seguinte erro no meu formulário Django 1.9

Vejam que no label fica com o `:>` no final.

**EU NÃO QUERO QUE APARECE O SINAL DE MAIOR (>) NO FINAL DO LABEL**
Ex: `Nome: >`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue meu codigo `forms.py`

```
class FormContact(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Nome', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    phone = forms.CharField(label='Telefone', max_length=13, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    message = forms.CharField(label='Mensagem', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}), max_length=500 )
```

*Mesmo sem o widget fica com erro*

HTML do `contato.html`

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for={{ field.label_tag }}> {{ field_label_tag }} </label>
        {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Qual erro vc esta recebendo?

Comment: @DenerCarvalho no label esta aparecendo o dois pontos e o sinal de maior (:>). Não deveria aparecer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você está usando código desnecessário. Veja nessa parte:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for={{ field.label_tag }}> {{ field_label_tag }} </label>
        {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

O `{{ field.label_tag }}` já vai criar pra você o label desse field envolto pela tag `label`. Mas como vc tá passando ele dentro de um label, o que acontece é o seguinte: na hora de renderizar o HTML, onde tem o `{{ field.label_tag }}` ele renderiza uma tag label completa, e **desconsidera** o que vem antes, que no caso é `<label for=`, porém o que vem depois é somente o `>`, que ele renderiza como um texto normal mesmo. Fora que você tem que lembrar que o conteúdo de um atributo tem que ficar dentro de aspas, como mostro mais abaixo.

Você pode ver isso aqui na [documentação](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields)

> {{ field.label_tag }}
>
> The field’s label wrapped in the appropriate HTML  tag. This
>   includes the form’s label_suffix. For example, the default
>   label_suffix is a colon:
>
> `<label for="id_email">Email address:</label>`

Para você ter o resultado que espera da forma como está fazendo, deveria usar o `{{ field.id_for_label }}`, que ficaria assim:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}"> {{ field.label }} </label>
        {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Excelente explicação. Irei testar e ja confirmo se deu certo

Comment: Deu certo é isso mesmo.
Eu tinha seguido um tutorial do Treina Web, vou avisar o instrutor tbm